# Date format is written as numerical value after multiple writes in JXL

Tags: java, android, jexcelapi

I am using JXL (JExcelAPI) to write data to excel. One of the columns is date column and I am adding a 
lot of rows per sheet (225+). I have 3 sheets and each sheet has a date column.

First sheet works fine. Second sheet works fine up to like 40 rows and then after that, instead of a date formatted value, I get just numerical value such as 42217.75. 3rd sheet continues to be numerical. 
Here is the method  I am call

```
public void writeCell(int columnPosition, int rowPosition, Date date, String format,
            WritableSheet sheet) throws RowsExceededException, WriteException{

        DateFormat customDateFormat = new DateFormat (format); 
        WritableCellFormat dateFormat = new WritableCellFormat (customDateFormat); 
        DateTime dateCell = new DateTime(columnPosition, rowPosition, date, dateFormat); 
        sheet.addCell(dateCell);
    }
```

And here is the calling block which offcourse is being called in a loop per sheet

```
writeCell(col,rows,task.getDateTime(),"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm",sheet);
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been years since I worked with the API, but the answer is that you need to reuse your cell formats... You can only create a limited number of them before excel starts having issues.